# Original gravity of ingredients

Tags: original-gravity

I would like to compute OG for some recipe. To do that I used to have a table, but I do not find it anynmore. Is there a table to calculate initial gravity of various ingredients in metric units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a table, you could use an free online calculator such as [Beer Calculus](http://beercalculus.hopville.com/recipe) to calculate the OG, along with other things about the recipe.

There are also several offline software programs that do this such as BeerSmith, although it is not free.

Answer (score 3):

John Palmer's book "How to Brew" offers a table of typical Malt yields including some of his own research on steeping yields. I enjoying calculating my recipes by hand rather then using brewing software, so I find the yield table helpful! Info can be found [here](http://www.howtobrew.com/section2/chapter12-4-1.html).

Answer (score 1):

I find myself using [this](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Malts_Chart) malt chart regularly.  It lists potential gravity, yeild, need to mash, SRM, and flavor/profile characteristics.